# Touching screen not working for move object or print message

Tags: unity, c#

It's simple, i want to move an object when i touch the screen, but code's not working, i tried to just put a console printing on it, but nothing happens:

```
void Update()
{
   if (Input.touchCount > 0)
   {
     Debug.Log("Touch");
   }
}
```

What am i doing wrong ?, thanks in advance !!

Comment: Welcome. Clarify the following, by any chance are you launching your project as a desktop application and expecting Unity to know to use the mouse to simulate touches? Did you try to debug as a mobile App, for Android: https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/mobile-touch/building-your-unity-game-android-device-testing?

Comment: Hi,no, I know that, the problem was that i have the camera inside the game object, but already solved it , thanks !!

Comment: @jsanchezs if you found the problem and a solution, you should post it as an answer, and then accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this standard touch code for mobile devices. You have to test it on a real device. If you use **print** or **debug.log** you have to use logcat on windows cmd to see logs on your computer, but you can simply make a UI text to display your test result.

```
void Update ()
{
    int activeTouches = Input.touchCount;

    if (activeTouches > 0) {
        print (activeTouches + " touch(es) detected");

        for (int i = 0; i < activeTouches; i++) {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (i);

            print ("Touch index " + touch.fingerId + " detected at position " + touch.position);

            switch (touch.phase) {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                print ("User did touch the screen");
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                print ("User dragging or moving his finger");
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                print ("User did lift up his finger");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already solved it, the issue was that i have the camera inside the game object, so the code I posted up worked good solving that. Thanks for your help anyway !!

Comment: This answer, while correct, does not answer the question.